# How can I add or subtract to get a number that I want based on the input I enter?

Tags: java

I would appreciate any input on this. The two numbers I need are 15 and 30 that give the positive print statement. But I also need a negative statement if you input any other numbers. Let's say for example I put in 20. I want the print to be: `System.out.println("Today is not a payday, you still need to wait" + daysTill + "days.");` with daysTill being 10 since it would take 10 more days till the next payday. This is the whole code i have so far:

```
public class MultiBranch
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int daysTill;
    int day;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    day = input.nextInt();

    daysTill = 0;

    if((day == 15) || (day == 30) )
    {
      System.out.println("Today is a payday, get ready to spend!");
    }  
    else
    {

      System.out.println("Today is not a payday, you still need to wait" + daysTill + "days.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your question is a bit vague but I think I get you. So id the number is not 15 or 30 you subtract based on the range it falls in. but what if it was greater than 30? do you want to display a negative answer. e.g if user entered 100 would the answer be `-70` ?

Comment: Well, it's based out of a 30 day month. So I'd assume it would just be an error after that since there are only 30 days in a month based on this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do a check

```
public class MultiBranch
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int daysTill = 0;
        int day;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        day = input.nextInt();

        if(day < 15){
            daysTill = 15 - day;
        }
        else{
            daysTill = 30 - day;
        }

        if((day == 15) || (day == 30) )
        {
            System.out.println("Today is a payday, get ready to spend!");
        }  
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Today is not a payday, you still need to wait" + daysTill + "days.");
        }
    }
}
```

You can also do a pre-check if input is greater than 30 then display an error.

Comment: It would be great if you can also point the side issues like java formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your code succinctly:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int day = input.nextInt();

if (day % 15 == 0)  {
    System.out.println("Today is a payday, get ready to spend!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Today is not a payday, you still need to wait " + (day < 15 ? 15 - day : 30 - day) + " days.");
}
```

---

`(day < 15 ? 15 - day : 30 - day)` is an implementation of the ternary operator in java.